# spring data jpa unable to create primary key getting this error SQL Error: 2289, SQLState: 42000 ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I am working with springboot, spring data jpa ,Oracle db. If i changed the schema i  am getting this error, without schema change everything is working fine.

I am not using sequence

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name = "CLIENTS")
    public class CLIENTS implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 123;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer clientId;

        @Column(name = "CODE")
        private Integer code;

        @Column(name = "REC_ID")
        private Integer recId;
//setters, getters, etc
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

"I am not using sequence". Sure you are. `GenerationType.AUTO` has chosen it for you out of `TABLE`, `SEQUENCE` and `IDENTITY`.

The sequence exists in the old schema, but if you change the schema you need to create the sequence in the new schema too.

Comment: thanks , for your reply , could you explain , how to know exists sequence in the old schema, how can i create same sequence in another schema

Comment: Those are separate questions. You should be able to find out easily with a little Googling how to view and create sequences in Oracle. Something like `select * from user_sequences;` should list them. Create a new one with [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion, I am searching for this past 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

Extend to **Kayaman**

**Oracle** @GeneratedValue(strategy = **GenerationType.AUTO**) Spring data jpa (or) Hibernate will create a sequence itself and it is used for all insertions , that sequence name **HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE**, we have to create into new schema, if not exist

To know the all sequences

```
SQL>select * from user_sequences;
```

For Creating sequence

```
SQL> create sequence HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE



SQL>create sequence HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE
    start with 1 increment by 1 maxvalue 9999999999999999999999999999 minvalue 1 cache 20;
```

FOR delete Sequence

```
SQL> drop   sequence HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE;
```